# Flutter app crash only on Xperia 10 III, how to simulate on android studio?

Tags: android, flutter

I tested my app bundle with firebase test lab, on some device and I test also with my real device at home and with friends. All run are OK except an Sony Xperia 10 III

Version Android : 12

Version de bande de base : bitra.gen-00411-25,bitra.gen-00411-25

Version du noyau :
4.19.157-perf+#1 Fri Apr 22 19:25:04 JST 2022

Numéro de build : 62.1.A.0.587 release-keys

How can I simulate this device on android studio ? Thank you

here is my manifest

```
<application
        android:label="XXXX"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="ca-app-pub-2985316085233177~9082095901"/>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">

            <!-- This keeps the window background of the activity showing
                 until Flutter renders its first frame. It can be removed if
                 there is no splash screen (such as the default splash screen
                 defined in @style/LaunchTheme). -->
            <meta-data
                android:name="io.flutter.app.android.SplashScreenUntilFirstFrame"
                android:value="true" />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />

    </application>
```

Comment: verify that you have the device in the AWS Device Farm

Comment: no sony or xperia mobile on AWS Device farm

Comment: sorry it was just a limited list

Answer (score 0):

Add sentry package then run the test it report the exception/problem to your dashboard so you can debug it

Answer (score 0):

Can you check `manifest file` for activity tag's property  `"android:exported" ="true"` or for other `activities` or `services` declared in `manifest` file ?

As from
`Android 12` thats needed for activities and services to declare with this property.

EDIT

You can simulate by taking `android-12` for simulator

Comment: I have well add  "android:exported" ="true" and   implementation 'androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx:2.7.0'
. I dont succesed to simulate on virtual android 12 cause of AVD kill

Comment: my  targetSdkVersion  was 30,  If I change to 31 it can be this ?

Comment: you can.  Do you have logs for crash ?

Comment: No I have no crash analytics, no physical device, no virtual, just all android 12 mobile crash

Comment: You can try by samsung remote test lab as well for andorid - 12 devices just need to install apk file to them  : https://developer.samsung.com/remote-test-lab. Is it crashing on start or something else ?

Comment: thank you, it will help me to test on android 12

Comment: On here simulation, I can't install my intern test version. it's available on my  physical device (in france) but on samsung virtual device I can only choose other country. So I choose one, on the playstore, my email is well detected as test but the app isn't load

Comment: You can run your test version apart from playstore version as well. as you have apk file is available with you then

Comment: I have test on Android 12 simulator, i have no crash, but on Physical android 12 always crash...

Comment: Its on start or on different screen ?

Comment: It crash on start

Comment: Thats related to splashscreen changes from android - 12. if you don't write exported ="true" for activity thats declared in manifets file then it will crash

Comment: I have well add   android:exported="true", I have edit my post and add my manifest to verify

Comment: A friend test on a physical samsung A53, There is no crash ... perhaps only crash on xperia X III and opppo A54

Comment: You can do one thing integrate firebase_crashlytics and check tjat build on Xperia and oppo. so, can recognize logs and check for solution

Comment: Wtf, I publish my app with firebase crashlytics. The person who have the Xperia have test and have no crash now... it will stay a mystery. Thank you for all, this was an inderect solution ^^